# factor in R Programming

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R Programming so I am just learning here and there. I recently got into these lines

```
x <- as.factor(rep(1:4, 2))
x
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 
# Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

But if I do

```
x <- factor(rep(1:4, 2))
```

that gives me the same result. So what is the difference between `factor` and `as.factor`? I get how factor is pulling same numbers out and making them levels, but I don't get what the exact differences are between `factor` and `as.factor`.

Comment: It is written in the help page. Please read it. From `?factor`  `as.factor` coerces its argument to a `factor`. It is an abbreviated form of `factor`. If you are quite new to R, I would recommend some reading from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: Plus `factor` gives you many useful options in the argument list, whereas `as.factor()` does not.

Comment: `factor` is normally used for building factors from scratch, and can take more arguments to fine-tune that process; `as.factor` is used for coercing existing variables into factors. Try typing just `factor` or `as.factor` (without the quotes) into the interpreter and you'll see what they actually do; `as.factor` mostly wraps `factor`.

Comment: @alistaire  It is what I said, thanks.

Comment: I personally like to think of the difference between these functions `as.fun` converts is for automatic conversion, and `fun` is for creation where more flexibility is required options. Richard already pointed this out to a degree.

Comment: I have read the factor and as.factor function, but its... too... u know... So, is it bad to just use factor for now? I dont see much difference between those two with my current knowledge. lol

Answer (score 0):

Five atomic data types in R (in least to most flexible order) are:  **logical, integer, double, and character.**

All elements of an atomic vector must be the same type, so when we attempt to combine different types they will be **coerced to the most flexible type**.

For example:

```
str(c("a", 1))
#>  chr [1:2] "a" "1"
```

Coercion often happens automatically. We can also **explicitly coerce** with as.factor(), as.character(), as.double(),as.integer(), or as.logical().

So, as pointed by @alistaire, to understand the difference between factor() and as.factor(), you must understand 'coercion'.

You can read abour coercion  at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/r-in-a/9781449358204/ch05s08.html

Also, as a beginer, you must read about data strucures in R at
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html